# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded using Array.forEach

Tags: javascript, sorting, jasmine

**src/QuickSort.js**

```
var quick_sort = function(unsorted) {
  if (unsorted.size <= 1)
    return unsorted;

  var pivot = unsorted.pop();
  var less = new Array();
  var greater = new Array();

  unsorted.forEach(function(element){
    if (element > pivot)
      less.push(element);
    else
      greater.push(element);
  });

  return quick_sort(less) + [pivot] + quick_sort(greater);
};
```

**spec/QuickSort.js**

```
describe("#quick_sort", function() {

  it("should sort the unsorted array", function() {
    var unsorted = [8, 2, 10, 5, 4, 9, 7, 1, 6, 3];
    var sorted = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    expect(quick_sort(unsorted)).toEqual(sorted);
  });

});
```

**Error message**

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at quick_sort (file://localhost/Users/jasonkim/projects/algorithm-everyday/quick_sort/javascript/src/QuickSort.js:9:12)
    at quick_sort (file://localhost/Users/jasonkim/projects/algorithm-everyday/quick_sort/javascript/src/QuickSort.js:16:10)
```

I am trying to test quick sort function using jasminejs. I am getting the error above. I have the terminating condition above `if (unsorted.size <= 1) { return unsorted }`. I am not sure why it's not terminating and goes into infinite loop.

Comment: Don't know about jasmine.js, does `unsorted.size` actually mean `unsorted.length`? Also, `+` operator on arrays doesn't seem to work that way in pure JS.

Comment: @Passerby, thanks! Make that as an answer, and I'll accept it. Ruby syntax was getting to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is the line

`if (unsorted.size <= 1)
    return unsorted;`

Which will never be reached as Arrays don't have a prototype property named `size`,
hence you don't return the Array when `unsorted` is empty and therefore going into an infinite loop, calling `quick_sort` with an empty `unsorted` until the call stack is exhausted.

The property you are looking for is `Array.prototype.length`, if you would change the line to

`if (unsorted.length <= 1)
    return unsorted;`

You function would properly return if it gets an empty array passed.

However theres a little thing, which can be noticed too,

`return quick_sort(less) + [pivot] + quick_sort(greater);`

If you are expecting to return a concatenated sorted array, you would have to change this line too.

You cannot simply concatenate Array by using an `+` operator, which calls,

`[[toPrimitive]]` and `[[toString]]` on `lRef` and `rRef` resulting in an concatenated String representation of your array.

Which would *(as you are effectivley `+`'ing all the pivot arrays, containing a single element)* in something like `10987654321`, instead of `[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]` what you may achieve.

Instead use `Array.prototype.concat` which concatenates arrays.

`return quick_sort(less).concat([pivot]).concat(quick_sort(greater));`

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Glutamat/m4Aq7/)